# Iterating over an array to create a nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to create a nested hash from an array that has several elements saved to it. I've tried experimenting with `each_with_object`, `each_with_index`, `each` and `map`.

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name, :city, :state, :zip, :hobby
  def initialize(name, hobby, city, state, zip)
    @name = name
    @hobby = hobby
    @city = city
    @state = state
    @zip = zip
  end

end

steve = Person.new("Steve", "basketball","Dallas", "Texas", 75444)
chris = Person.new("Chris", "piano","Phoenix", "Arizona", 75218)
larry = Person.new("Larry", "hunting","Austin", "Texas", 78735)
adam = Person.new("Adam", "swimming","Waco", "Texas", 76715)

people = [steve, chris, larry, adam]

people_array = people.map do |person|
  person = person.name, person.hobby, person.city, person.state, person.zip
end
```

Now I just need to turn it into a hash. One issue I am having is, when I'm experimenting with other methods, I can turn it into a hash, but the array is still inside the hash. The expected output is just a nested hash with no arrays inside of it.

```
# Expected output ... create the following hash from the peeps array:
#
# people_hash = {
#   "Steve" => {
#     "hobby" => "golf",
#     "address" => {
#       "city" => "Dallas",
#       "state" => "Texas",
#       "zip" => 75444
#     }
#   # etc, etc
```

Any hints on making sure the hash is a nested hash with no arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
person_hash = Hash[peeps_array.map do |user|
  [user[0], Hash['hobby', user[1], 'address', Hash['city', user[2], 'state', user[3], 'zip', user[4]]]]
end]
```

Basically just use the ruby [Hash [] method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) to convert each of the sub-arrays into an hash

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass `people`?

```
people.each_with_object({}) do |instance, h|
  h[instance.name] = { "hobby"   => instance.hobby,
                       "address" => { "city"  => instance.city,
                                      "state" => instance.state,
                                      "zip"   => instance.zip } }
end
```